# How do I move window to specific workplace via keyboard?

Tags: unity, workspaces, shortcut-keys

In 11.11 keyboard settings there are `Move window to workspace N` options (N is the workspace number). But they do not work.

Is there a way to bind key for moving window to a specific workspace/viewport?

Comment: I know this isn't exactly what you want, but I use the keyboard to move windows between workspaces all the time, so this could be a useful workaround. I press Alt-Space (which brings up the window menu), press W (Move to another Workspace), and then select the workspace number (1, 2, 3, ...)

Answer (score 3):

That's either a bug or a consequence of a tweaked environment.

To verify the keyboard shortcut visit the gear in the upper right hand corner,
select system settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts -> navigation.
`Move Window one workspace to the [direction]` should be defined. If it is and
you're still having problems then try resetting unity to defaults.

To reset unity to it's defaults: `unity --reset`:

- [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Once that's done: `CTRL+ALT+SHIFT [ARROW]` will take the active window and place
it on the desktop you're pointing to. `CTRL+ALT [ARROW]` just switches the
current desktop.

UPDATE:

After clarifying the bug with the user. I found out that this is actually a known bug.

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/348848
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/291854
- http://osdir.com/ml/ubuntu-bugs/2011-06/msg40967.html

It looks like it's getting lost in the wishlist status. I would recommend filing a new bug to bring fresh attention to it. I agree that it's a bug. If it isn't an option then it should be removed from Navigation shortcuts to begin with. I think I will to, this would be very useful.

Comment: I am talking about moving window to a specific workspace. Not left/right/up/down. See `Navigation` -> `Move window to workspace 1`.

Comment: I filed my bug, you should too. I noticed in playing these shortcuts that the other set of disabled shortcuts "Switch to workspace X" **does work**.

Comment: Thanks. I have [reported the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/898087).

Comment: I don't suppose there's any work-around, either?

Comment: @BrianWhite: there is, with CCSM, see my answer.

Comment: Anyone interested in having this bug fixed should subscribe to those bug reports so that the developers can see how many people want it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is still not working in the original Settings in 14.04.

However you can make it work if you install [CompizConfig Settings Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/) (CCSM), activate the plugin "Put", and bind its settings in the section "Put to arbitrary viewport".

The bindings may look a little strange (`<Shift><Control><Alt>1` shows up as `<Shift><Control><Alt>exclam`), but it's working for me.

Note that when you move the window to another viewport, the current viewport in view changes as well (e.g. putting a window from viewport 1 to viewport 2 might make you switch your view to viewport 2). To avoid this, go to CCSM->Put->Misc.Options, and tick "Unfocus Window".

I use CCSM->Put to move windows to arbitrary viewports without changing current view, and the Ubuntu Settings with arrows to move windows to adjacents viewports and moving the view (following the window) at the same time.

Comment: The 'Put' Plugin isn't working for me, either.

Comment: This is a great answer, but it doesn't work for me. Compiz recognizes the keyboard shortcut, but always moves the window to viewport 2, even if I have it set for 1, 3, 4, etc. I can't move that window (that I just moved to viewport 2) or any other window to any other viewport. Odd.