# move window a workspace down

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, workspaces

I am using Gnome on ubuntu. I have a question if there is a short-cut to move a window down. If I right click the title bar there is a command to move the window a workspace up or down, I would like to have that behaviour in a short-cut. Is this possible?

Note that the command ctrl-alt-shift-arrow is not an answer to this question, because it moves the window down AND moves the view down along with the window; it therefore does not behave in the same way as the "move workspace up or down" option that I find when right-clicking the title bar.

Answer (score 0):

In Gnome on Ubuntu 15.04

- Access **Settings** -> **keyboard** -> **shortcuts** -> **Navigation**
- Options are available to set Keys for moving window to desired workspace
- Default : Shift+Alt+Super+Home

Reference : AskUbuntu - [How do I move window to specific workplace via keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83761/how-do-i-move-window-to-specific-workplace-via-keyboard)

---

Comment: "Down" isn't "First"